# When to stop using Elixir?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-elixir

If you have a python database wrapper using Elixir, with a pretty straightforward 'Active Record' design (1 object to 1 table), but then you begin to expand...

At what point should you stop using Elixir? Are there any common milestones/symptoms that should indicate these points?

If these points are arrived at, is it necessary to abandon Elixir and transfer purely to SQLAlchemy, or is it always ok to leave the Elixir layers on top, and *silently* extend through SQLAlchemy?

Comment: This is way too vague and properly better suited for the [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think your question is too vague and overly broad to be answered here on SO; see the [FAQ#dontask]. If you have more concrete problems (preferably involving some code), feel free to ask those! The fact that this specific question has a simple answer (don't use Elixir *at all*) doesn't change that the question itself is really too vague.

Comment: @frb: This question is way too open ended and non-constructive even for Programmers.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLAlchemy has an excellent [declarative layer](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/extensions/declarative.html) itself. Elixir has been obsoleted for some time now. As a result, Elixir has not seen [any development](http://elixir.ematia.de/trac/browser) for over 2 years, the project has been abandoned.

The point to abandon Elixir is Right Now.

Comment: Lol, fair enough. Has it been replaced? I think 'ActiveMapper' was once an option. Have both of these been deprecated in favor of the declarative layer?

Comment: ActiveMapper and Elixir where separate projects from SQLAlchemy, and Elixir was meant as a replacement for ActiveMapper. Since Elixir has been abandoned, I guess it's authors felt SQLAlchemy's own declarative option was good enough for their usecases.

Comment: @user2097818: According to the Elixir homepage, the project was started in 2006, and SQLAlchemy only added it's own declarative extension in 2008 (version 0.4.3); as an external project Elixir would always be running to keep up with SQLAlchemy's own declarative base. My guess is that at some point it was no longer worth the effort.

Comment: thanks much for the effort